# What do each of these numbers represent when `print(transform.rotation);` is executed in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I execute the line `print(transform.rotation);` a message like this comes up in the command screen:

`(-0.4, -0.9, 0.0, 0.0)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
FireballActive:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/Folder/Script.cs:14)`

I'm interested in what the 4 numbers are in the brackets and how to address them in code like `transform.rotation.x`. What do each of the numbers represent?

Comment: As quaternions are a bit complex matter for a non-mathematician like me, I will try to explain my simple non-math understanding of them. In unity transform.rotation returns quaternion. Quaternions are 4D vectors. I think about them as 3D angle. Basically quaternion describes if you take an object, how it will end up rotated in 3d after applying that quaternion.

Comment: In unity quaternions are useful if you want to cache a rotation that you can later apply or add, subtract from it another rotation. But keep in mind that with quaternions a+b is different than b+a. If you are just interested in the angles values then you can use transform.eulerAngles.

Comment: Please use the API: [`transform.rotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) => [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the fields of a [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation). When you convert your rotation to an angle-axis, three of those numbers is the axis scaled by sine of the half of that angle. The fourth is the cosine of the half of that angle.

Does it sound too complicated? Don't worry, it is! You are not supposed to go `transform.rotation.x` ever. I think this is one of the design flaws of Unity's API. You have "rotation" with x, y and z in the UI and you expect to be able to say `transform.rotation.x` to access that. What you see in the UI actually is closer to `transform.eulerAngles.x`.

Quaternions are quite useful though, but through the methods defined in the `Quaternion` class, not by accessing their `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` fields.

Here are the takeaway points.

- Never access the individual elements of a `Quaternion` (don't do `transform.rotation.x`).
- Use `Quaternion` as an object. Don't worry about what actually it contains, worry about what it represents ("it's this rotation I'm looking for"). If you really want to tinker with them, convert them to something that makes sense to you (`q.eulerAngles`, `Quaternion.ToAngleAxis(q)`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

the two zeros are for instance say how a ball rotates. tilted, angles if that makes sense? the ball can spin longitude, altitude (now the 0 0 would make the ball turn and it would look like it is out of ballance) it would sway and very easy get you lot of errors. it also use much more memory.  I have been told to leave them as default :

float x;
    void Update () {

```
    x += Time.deltaTime * 10;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x,0,0);

}
```